# Hide sensitive arguments passed with spark-submit on the Job Page

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I've recently found that Spark displays the command line arguments passed into the spark-submit command right there on the Job Page. I need to redact sensitive arguments, such as passwords from the page.

Exact location: **Environment** Tab > **System Properties** Section > **sun.java.command** property.

Example of what is shown:

```
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster --class com.xxx.xxx.sparkexport.bus.SparkExport --jar file:/xx/hadoop/jar/xx/xx.jar --arg -c --arg jdbc:dbserv://xx.xx.xx.com:2633 --arg -d --arg ActionS --arg -D --arg ActionS --arg -C --arg xx_Hadoop --arg -q --arg SELECT xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx FROM xyy WHERE zz= '2016-12-28' AND aa= '11' --arg -t --arg bb--executor-memory 8192m --executor-cores 1 --properties-file /hadoop/yarn/nm/usercache/xx/appcache/application_1482736206018_6501/container_e134_1482736206018_6501_01_000001/__spark_conf__/__spark_conf__.properties
```

I've searched online with no luck. I'm thinking maybe if i can locate and modify that string (on the SparkContext object) will it be reflected on the page? How can that property be modified?

I consider this a very important security issue to solve (or work around). Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is necessary logging information. I think that the most you can do is to control who access this logs

Comment: @Yeikel Sure!. But a couple of our spark-submit jobs actually need to pass spark a password. So, i want to edit that property. It should be possible, my understanding is that SparkContext object properties are just  a dictionary. But i'm curious, are you referring to a way in which i can control access on a property basis? Or just the whole tab?

Comment: in general you should be able control who can and who can't have acess to the logs in general. If you control that , it does not really matter if you pass the password as an argument because only people with the permissions are going to be able to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i what i ended up doing is to tweak the code used to excecute our spark jobs, like:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName(application.getApplicationName())
            .set("sun.java.command", "Dummy Command String...");
```

Then, use that .JAR to create all of our Spark Job Tools. Dependencies handled by MAVEN make this super easy. The jobs get created as they should, just that particular property gets changed.